# Passing values from another class

Tags: java, constructor

I have three classes.

Input.java (This is the gui class)
This class takes in 3 values thru textfields and has button to trigger an event and finally a label to show the result of the values (double values)

```
package javalearning;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Input extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Input
     */
    public Input() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        result_lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        value1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        value2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        value3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btn1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        result_lbl.setText("jLabel1");

        btn1.setText("jButton1");
        btn1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(99, 99, 99)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(btn1)
                    .addComponent(result_lbl)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(value1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 61, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(value2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(value3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)))
                .addContainerGap(100, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                .addComponent(value1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(value2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(value3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(result_lbl)
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello");
         Computation actual_triangle = new Computation(Double.parseDouble(value1.getText()),Double.parseDouble(value2.getText()),Double.parseDouble(value3.getText()));

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Input.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Input.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Input.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Input.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Input().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton btn1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel result_lbl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField value1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField value2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField value3;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Computation.java
This is the place all the values are will be computed to produce a result

```
package javalearning;
public class Computation {

    private double side_a, side_b, side_c,result;


   public Computation(double side_a, double side_b, double side_c)
   {
       this.side_a = side_a;
       this.side_b = side_b;
       this.side_c = side_c;
      valueException ive = new valueException();
      //here if there is a message being sent from the valueException method then the message have to be relayed back to the Input.result_lbl.setText()
      ive.checkvalidation(side_a, side_b, side_c);

   }

   public double getsSide_A()
   {
       return side_a;
   }

   public void setsSide_A(double side_a)
   {
       this.side_a = side_a;
   }

   public double getsSide_B()
   {
       return side_b;
   }

   public void setsSide_B(double side_b)
   {
       this.side_b = side_b;
   }

   public double getsSide_C()
   {
       return side_c;
   }

   public void setsSide_C(double side_c)
   {
       this.side_c = side_c;
   }

   public double calculateArea()
    {
        result = Math.sqrt(side_a*side_b*side_c);
        return result;
    }

}
```

valueException.java

This is the class that outputs all kinds of errors depending on the user inputs,
example 1: the user types in a string for either one or all the textfields then a message will return to the label class.
But this is the twist, this class have to be called from the **Computation.java not** from **Input.java**

```
package javalearning;
public class valueException {

    String message;
    double a_side, b_side,c_side,result;


    public String checkvalidation(double a_side, double b_side, double c_side)
    {
        if((a_side + b_side > c_side)||(a_side + c_side > b_side)||(c_side + b_side > a_side))
        {

           //NOTHING TO DO JUST PROCEED BACK TO COMPUTATION and go the Computation.calculatearea() method

        }

        else
        {
            message = "The values you entered cannot form a shape";
        }
      return message;  
    }

}
```

Problem 1:
So I am having difficulty figuring out how to relay back the message from the valueException class back to the Computation class and from there to the Input class?

Problem 2:
If there is nothing wrong with the entered values in Input.java then revert back the process to  the Computation class to do the rest of the program , as this is the only class that is calling the valueException class, I am not sure the exact code to put in.

I have commented the problems where I am facing the problem, I put in these comments at places where I think they shld be.

Comment: have you try to use a class which communicate with the two modules? This class could take the modules as member variables and work with them through public methods and store computation results.

Comment: @JanKoester I think the poor guy is already struggling with the classes he has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think the reason you are confused is because, you are not sure how to pass values between classes. 
Since you say you are starting to learn programming (appreciate you for that). But you have take every opportunity to learn and explore new things, but not too much as this might deviate you from the objective. So what you can do for your 
problem 1:
You can relay back the message from the exception class to computation class then again relay back to the input class

problem 2:
a simple break; will break the statement and returns back control to the original point of code where this loop/or in your case the class it is called from.

I am assuming you know how to code the rest.

Comment: that was a simple solution I passed the message from exception to computation, but ur break cannot be used in here, and after some research I used while loop. Tks

Answer (score 1):

You have a View (`Input`) and a Model (`Computation`).  You need a `Controller` to sit between the two and know what to do about telling what to do next.  That'll complete the MVC pattern.

The `Controller` will accept events from the `View`, validate and package input values, marshal services and `Model` objects to fulfill use cases, and decide what the next `View` should be based on the outcome of the use case.

Think about a service-oriented architecture: interface-based Services that the Controllers can call on to fulfill use cases.  I think it's best to encapsulate use cases in Services rather than Controllers, because Controllers tend to be closely tied to a particular View.  If you decide that you'd rather have a web-based View you'll have to start all over without services, but if you have them the new web (or mobile or tablet) controllers can simply access your service layer and keep on humming.

UPDATE:

Okay, after reading your protest for "simple", here's what I would recommend.  I think the problem is your exception class.  You've written it as if it were a validator class.  I think you should only throw that exception if the Controller that I'm recommending does its job and finds an invalid situation.

```
package controller;

// Making the Controller the ActionListener is the key.  Take it away from the View.
public class ShapeController implements ActionListener {
    private Input inputView;

    public Controller() {
        this.inputView = new Input();
        this.addActionListener(this);  // Make the Controller respond to action events from the View.
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double a_side, b_side, c_side;
        // Get the input values from the input view
        if((a_side + b_side > c_side)||(a_side + c_side > b_side)||(c_side + b_side > a_side)) {
            Computation comp = new Computation()
           // perform your calculation; all is well    
        } else {
            // Problem; throw an exception
            throw new InvalidShapeException();
        }
        // figure out where to go next
    }
}
```

I think your value_exception class is wrong.  Use it as I showed above and write it like this:

```
package controller;

public class InvalidShapeException extends RuntimeException {
    // Add whatever you want for messages and details.
    public InvalidShapeException() { super(); }
    public InvalidShapeException(String s) { super(s); }
    public InvalidShapeException(Throwable t) { super(t); }
    public InvalidShapeExceptionI(String s, Throwable t) { super(s, t); }
}
```

Comment: No no, MVC this is java 101 very very basic I am just starting to learn programming let alone JAVA, so a very simple solution will do, tks!

Comment: I think this *is* simple.  We're talking about adding one class.  How hard is that?

Comment: But this is not a web-based this is a standalone, even though the MVC concept looks more interesting but not quite there yet, where I can decide upon the next View which means changing the whole entire screen, my primary question is still passing the values from different classes

Comment: Could you perhaps show what the class should have as this is relatively new to me..

Comment: @noobprogrammer You are wrong when you say MVC is only for Web applications. Beginner or not, there is not harm in learning what is the right way of doing something. Don't be like this if you want to be a good programmer. Be open to new ideas and be hungry for learning the right way to do something.

Comment: Not quite there yet?  MVC predates the Internet by quite a lot.  It's an old Smalltalk idea.  You don't know what you're talking about, noobprogrammer.  I've already wasted enough time on you, with no benefit whatsoever.